# Adding mapper to myBatis configuration in Java

Tags: java, mybatis

I want to migrate from XML configuration to Java configuration.

```
sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().setEnvironment(new Environment("development", new org.apache.ibatis.transaction.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory(), getDataSouroce()));
```

I managed to replace all `<environments>` section with Java configuration (I have removed `<environments>` from XML configuration file), but I can't get rid of:

```
 <mappers><mapper resource="mailbox/db/map/FileMapper.xml"/> </mappers>
```

I tried to write:

> sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().addMapper(FileMapper.class);

but there are exceptions:

```
SqlSession sqlSession = MyBatisConnectionFactory.instance.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession();

    FileExample fe = new FileExample();
    Criteria f = fe.createCriteria().andIdBetween(0L, 5L);
    FileMapper mapper = (FileMapper) sqlSession.getMapper(FileMapper.class);
    List<File> allRecords = mapper.selectByExample(fe);

// Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for mailbox.db.dao.FileMapper.selectByExample
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using below abstract mapper factory where DbUtil.getInstance().getDataSource() and registerMappers() are the key points.

```
public abstract class AbstractMapperFactory implements MapperFactory {

    private ThreadLocal<SqlSessionManager> sessionManagerThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<SqlSessionManager>();

    public <T> T getMapper(Class<T> clazz) throws DaoException {
        if(sessionManagerThreadLocal.get() == null) {
            initialize();
        }
        return sessionManagerThreadLocal.get().getMapper(clazz);
    }

    public void closeSession() {
        if(sessionManagerThreadLocal.get() != null) {
            sessionManagerThreadLocal.get().close();
            sessionManagerThreadLocal.remove();
        }
    }

    private void initialize() throws DaoException {
        Environment environment = new Environment("env", new ManagedTransactionFactory(), DbUtil.getInstance().getDataSource());
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration(environment);
        registerMappers(configuration);
        sessionManagerThreadLocal.set(SqlSessionManager.newInstance(new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(configuration))); 
    }

    protected abstract void registerMappers(Configuration configuration);

}
```

Where DbUtil.getInstance().getDataSource() is responsible for getting the java.sql.DataSource instance, whether it is managed or simple.

registerMappers() is an abstract method where subclass can register their mappers using code like below:

```
protected void registerMappers(Configuration configuration) {
    configuration.addMapper(PartMapper.class);
    configuration.addMapper(StatusMapper.class);
    configuration.addMapper(NoteTypeMapper.class);
    configuration.addMapper(AssetTypeMapper.class);
}
```