# Using SqlSession in MyBatis

Tags: java, vaadin, mybatis

I am sort of beginner in MyBatis, and I was going through below link of their documentation:
[MyBatis Getting Started](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/getting-started.html#SqlSession)

What it suggest is:

> Each thread should have its own instance of SqlSession. Instances of SqlSession are not to be shared and are not thread safe.

From above line what I understood is, we should use it in this way:

```
SqlSession session = // getting one instance of SqlSession as suggested in above link  
List<Integer> result = session.selectList("getUsersId");
session.close();
```

So similarly where ever required, I need to create new SqlSession each time and close them. is there any better way to use it ? From better way I mean a better way to write code, pattern which should create `SqlSession` for me and close it automatically.
(I am using Vaadin and MyBatis.)

Answer (score 0):

SqlSession lifetime scope is method or Http request. So if method is return or request completed, it will be close auto.

Answer (score 0):

SqlSession is AutoCloseable

When you use it [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), Autocloseable class invoke default close method

The correct pattern would be

```
try (SqlSession session = // getting one instance of SqlSession as suggested in above link) {
    List<Integer> result = session.selectList("getUsersId");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html). With such an approach each thread will have its own SqlSession. Note that thread should cleanup after itself so closing an opened sql session should be a part of it.

More on this:

- [When and how should I use a ThreadLocal variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817856/when-and-how-should-i-use-a-threadlocal-variable)
- [Adding mapper to myBatis configuration in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14273270/2754530)